# Files get executable when copied

Tags: permissions, filesystems, rsync, cp, executable

So I just bought a new Samsung T7 Portable SSD. I initially intended to format it to exFAT, for use with both Windows, MacOS and Linux, but upon inspection, the disk comes with a default file system of `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`. I didn't know that was a thing, but I decided to test it out.

To test it out, I simply copied a few ASCII text files to the disk, but regardless of method for copying, and file extension, they all get the executable flag set. I don't understand why. Why is it like this, and how can I avoid it? I want the files copied exactly as they are.

Complete output showing changed permissions.

```bash
user@ubuntu:~$ echo "test text file" > test.txt
user@ubuntu:~$ echo "test test test" > test
user@ubuntu:~$ echo "print('test')" > test.py
user@ubuntu:~$
user@ubuntu:~$ ls -l test*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 15 July  18 01:20 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 14 July  18 01:20 test.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 15 July  18 01:20 test.txt
user@ubuntu:~$
user@ubuntu:~$ mkdir /media/user/T7/testdir
user@ubuntu:~$ cp test /media/user/T7/testdir/
user@ubuntu:~$ rsync test.txt /media/user/T7/testdir/
user@ubuntu:~$ rsync -a test.py /media/user/T7/testdir/
user@ubuntu:~$
user@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /media/user/T7/testdir
total 384
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 15 July  18 01:23 test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 14 July  18 01:20 test.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 15 July  18 01:23 test.txt
```

Here you can see I've tried both `cp`, `rsync` and `rsync -a`, but they end up as executables every single time. Why?

Edit:
I tried doing exactly the same to a WD HDD that comes with NTFS by default. There, the files get the 777 permission (`rwxrwxrwx`).
Does it have something to do with the disk itself? Clearly my knowledge is lacking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HPFS/NTFS/exFAT` is a partition type. It *claims* the partition contains one of the named filesystem types, but that does not have to be the complete truth.

Try `lsblk -o +FSTYPE` or look into /proc/mounts while the partition is mounted to see the *actual* filesystem type.

Anyway, HPFS is unlikely, so the SSD most likely is already formatted with either a NTFS or exFAT filesystem.

In terms of use with Linux, both these filesystem types lack a certain property: **they don't support Unix-style ownership/group/permissions information**.

NTFS has ACLs which could be used to implement Unix-style ownerships and permissions; it could even support Linux's ACLs if necessary. But before it can do that, the Linux NTFS driver **needs a conversion table** between Unix style user and group IDs (UIDs and GIDs, basically just simple numbers) and Windows-style security IDs (SIDs: long strings of groups of numbers separated by dashes). If this is not provided, the driver won't be able to know how it should record the file permissions information on the filesystem, and it falls back to working just like with a filesystem that cannot support the concept of users and permissions at all.

exFAT is a filesystem designed for removable media: it is assumed that whover physically possesses the media will be able to read everything stored on it anyway, so there is not much point for permissions. So like FAT32 and other filesystems in the FAT family, it has no real concept of file ownerships and permissions at all, and no way to store them.

But Linux - or any Unix-like system - fundamentally requires that every file must be associated with *some* user and *some* group, and *must* have at least the classic set of user/group/other permissions, or a more complex ACL. All the system calls and operating system commands expect every file to have those. So if the filesystem does not support those, **the filesystem driver needs to fake them**.

For the purpose of providing fake ownerships and permissions when the filesystem has none, both the NTFS-3G and exFAT filesystem drivers support a set of mount options which you can use to define two sets of permissions: one for all files, and another for all directories. Without being able to store permissions information to the metadata of each file on the filesystem, that's all you can get.

The difference between the WD NTFS HDD and the Samsung SSD indicates that the Samsung most likely already has an exFAT filesystem on it, and the exFAT and NTFS filesystems simply have different default settings for faking the permissions... or the NTFS HDD has an ACL on its root directory that would be expressed in Windows as `Everyone - Full Control`, configured to be inherited by any new file or sub-directory.

Since "Everyone" in Windows is a globally-defined standard SID, it's one of the very few SIDs the Linux NTFS driver will be able to understand by default.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!  
`lsblk` lists the FSTYPE as `exfat`, while `/proc/mounts` says it's `fuseblk` (which is NTFS, it seems). Not sure what's going on there. Guess I'll just try and format it.  
I did try to put exfat on the WD drive with fdisk, but neither Windows nor MacOS managed to access the drive. That will be a deep dive for tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: `fuseblk` means the file system is being accessed through a FUSE driver rather than a kernel driver. That’s plausible for an exFAT volume.